# Column with div style and div id

Tags: class, html, formatting

For some reason I cannot get the text in my middle column (of three columns) to respond to any classes or styles I apply to it.  I'm just trying to slide the text in the middle column over to the right a little bit.

**CSS (stylesheet):**

```
#footer-address {
font-size:20px;
padding-left:20px;
}

#nav-foot{
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-width:1px 0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0px;
text-align:left;
font-size:12px;
}


#nav-foot li{
display:inline;
}

#nav-foot a{
display:inline-block;
padding:20px 0 20px 0;
}

#nav-social  {
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-width:1px 0;
display:inline;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0px;
float: left;
} 

#nav-social li{
display:inline;
}

#nav-social a{
display:inline-block;
padding:20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div style="width:30%; float:left; margin: 10px 0 10px 0; position:relative;">

<ul id="nav-foot">
    <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/employment/">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>

        <div id="footer-address" style="width:30%; float:left; margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px; position:relative;">
                375 6th St. </br>
                Atlanta, GA  30308 </br>
                Phone:  <a href="tel:+1-404-981-3934">404-981-3934</a> </br>
                Email:  <a href="mailto:admin@perimetermaids.com ">admin@perimetermaids.com </a>
        </div>

        <div style="width:30%; float:left; margin: 10px 0 10px 0; position:relative;">
        <ul id="nav-social">
                <a href="www.facebook.com/PerimeterMaids" target="_blank" class='social'><i class="awesome-facebook hover-fade" style="color:#ffffff; font-size:22px;"></i></a>

                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/perimetermaids" target="_blank" class='social'><i class="awesome-twitter hover-fade" style="color:#ffffff; font-size:22px;"></i></a></li>

                <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/111070135673056939333/posts" target="_blank" class='social'><i class="awesome-google-plus hover-fade" style="color:#ffffff; font-size:22px;"></i></a></li>

                <li><a href="http://pinterest.com/perimetermaids" target="_blank" class='social'><i class="awesome-pinterest hover-fade" style="color:#ffffff; font-size:22px;"></i></a></li>

                <li><a href="http://perimetermaids.com/contact/#contact-wrapper" target="_blank" class='social'><i class="awesome-envelope-alt hover-fade" style="color:#ffffff; font-size:22px;"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
```

Sorry if the code is sloppy or the formatting of my question, however, I'm really scratching my head as to why this won't work.
My URL is http://perimetermaids.com/test if anybody needs that as well.  This is for the black footer area.  Thanks for the help, and hope you all have an awesome weekend!

Comment: This is NOT an answer, but a quick suggestion - when my layouts start acting up like this, I throw the content inside a div (a div inside your footer-address div) and center that div. It's not elegant but it works a chunk of the time for me.

Comment: Thanks Julie, I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: which **column** is considered to be the **middle column** ? [ also don't use inline styles, please]